# Error getting sitemap generator settings. Sitefinity

Tags: sitemap, sitefinity

Hi I'm working with and I Sitefinity happening an error when I try to generate the sitemap manually or automatically, when I try to enter the section sitemap shoot me an error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCN2x.png)

Comment: Can you please check is there any logs related to your problem in folder App_Data/Sitefinity/Logs?

Comment: Could you check in SitemapGenerator module is installed and activated in Administration -> Modules and Services?